# Passivity in State Space Models

Tags: nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

Suppose I have the state space system $a\dot{x} = -x + \frac{1}{k}h(x) + u$, and output $y = h(x)$, where $a,k > 0$. The only information I'm given about $h(x)$ is that $h\in[0,k]$. I want to show that the system is passive using the storage function $V(x) = a\int_{0}^{x}h(\sigma)\ d\sigma$. The definition of a passive system is $u^\intercal y \geq \dot{V}$ for all $(x,u)$. Thus,

$$
\dot{V} = ah(x) \dot{x} = h(x) (-x + h(x)/k + u) = \frac{1}{k}h(x)(h(x) - kx) + h(x) u.
$$

Rearranging this gives

$$
h(x)u = yu = \dot{V} + \frac{1}{k}h(x)[kx-h(x)].
$$

In order to prove passivity, I need to show that $\frac{1}{k}h(x)[kx - h(x)] \geq 0$, for all $x$. However, all I'm given is that $h\in[0,k]$ so how can this be true in general? Am I missing something really simple here?